# Fill field type with distinct values of entity field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the entity `Place` with `id, name, street, city` properties. I want to make filter field `City` filled with the values of distinct cities available on saved places.

I have the following in my FormFieldType

```
$builder->add('city', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Place',
        'property' => 'city',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
            $alias = 'p';
            $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder($alias);

            return $qb
                ->groupBy($alias . '.city')
                ->orderBy($alias . '.city', 'ASC');
        }
    ));
```

Which gives me the following html

```
<select id="place_filter_city" name="place_filter[city]">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="143">City 1</option>
   <option value="1">City 4</option>
   <option value="69">City 3</option><option>
</select>
```

The value of option is the ID of the entity, the city was taken from. I need the city name itself to be a value and a label of the selection. How can I archieve that?

Comment: How about using choice type, with private property containing your desired key - value pairs, retrieved and formatted from controller and supplied through form class construct.

Comment: Here is what you're looking for : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html